# @JsonProperty not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I get the following exception when i consume a restful webservice using Spring RestTemplate

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "IMP-SourceTxnId" (class com.model.ResponseBaseParameters) not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: , "sourceTxnId", "incommTxnId", "responseCode", "responseText"])

at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@2f2ddd7c; line: 1, column: 130] (through reference chain: com.incomm.ife.model.rogers.RogersTransactionResponse["responseBaseParameters"]->com.incomm.ife.model.rogers.ResponseBaseParameters["IMP-SourceTxnId"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1159)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:449)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2094)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:123)
... 54 more
```

The response parameter is

```
{

  "responseBaseParameters":  

{

  "responseCode": "32",

  "responseText": "Invalid Request",

  "incommTxnId": null,

  "IMP-SourceTxnId": "551932ba-6af4-44f9-ab98-db5bc96e962b"

 }

}
```

and my POJO class is

```
public class ResponseBaseParameters {

private String responseCode;

private String responseText;
private String incommTxnId;
@JsonProperty("IMP-SourceTxnId")
private String sourceTxnId;

public String getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
    this.responseCode = responseCode;
}

public String getResponseText() {
    return responseText;
}

public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
    this.responseText = responseText;
}

public String getIncommTxnId() {
    return incommTxnId;
}

public void setIncommTxnId(String incommTxnId) {
    this.incommTxnId = incommTxnId;
}

public String getSourceTxnId() {
    return sourceTxnId;
}

public void setSourceTxnId(String sourceTxnId) {
    this.sourceTxnId = sourceTxnId;
}

}
```

Please any insight as to why i am getting this error. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace

Comment: What happens if you try to serialize your POJO to JSON? Does the serialized version have the field?

Comment: I haven't tried to serialize the same object because i don't have a need to.

Comment: I think @dimoniy is suggesting you should try just to see what happens.

Comment: When i serialize i got the following as output seBaseParameters":
            {"IMP-SourceTxnId":"abc123",
        "responseCode":"0",
        "responseText":"Success",
        "incommTxnId":"-4282972720901144148",
        "sourceTxnId":"abc123"}}

Comment: Do you by any chance have two jackson libraries in your classpath (codehaus/jackson1 and fasterxml/jackson2) ? If so, you may have used the wrong annotation (actually the right annotation, but imported from the wrong package).

Comment: Yes i do but in a way. The codehaus/jackson1 is for another project which the second project uses. The second project has the fasterxml/jackson2

Comment: Can you check whether your IDE imported the right annotation as `JsonProperty` ?

Comment: This was the imported object org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty

Comment: This seems to be it ! Just change that to the proper `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` import and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To Map coorect your Json by Jackson you must create another object that contains the POJO class, some this like that:

Your POJO class:

```
public static class ResponseBaseParameters {

    private String responseCode;
    private String responseText;
    private String incommTxnId;
    @JsonProperty("IMP-SourceTxnId")
    private String sourceTxnId;


    // Getter & Setter Methods...

}
```

then The Class which contains your Your POJO class **`ResponseBaseParameters`**:

```
public class ResponseBase{


    @JsonProperty("responseBaseParameters")
    private ResponseBaseParameters responseBaseParameters;


    public ResponseBaseParameters getResponseBaseParameters() {
        return responseBaseParameters;
    }

    public void setResponseBaseParameters(ResponseBaseParameters responseBaseParameters) {
        this.responseBaseParameters = responseBaseParameters;
    }
}
```

if you try this, it will work

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String s = """
                {
                  "responseBaseParameters":
                {
                  "responseCode": "32",
                  "responseText": "Invalid Request",
                  "incommTxnId": null,
                  "IMP-SourceTxnId": "551932ba-6af4-44f9-ab98-db5bc96e962b"
                 }
                }
                """;

        ResponseBase r =  JsonMapper.builder().build().readValue(s, ResponseBase.class);
        System.out.println(JsonMapper.builder().build().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(r));
    }
```

Output is:

```
{
  "responseBaseParameters" : {
    "responseCode" : "32",
    "responseText" : "Invalid Request",
    "incommTxnId" : null,
    "IMP-SourceTxnId" : "551932ba-6af4-44f9-ab98-db5bc96e962b"
  }
}
```

Let Me know if you any problem with this solution.