# @JsonProperty not overriding boolean and still removing the `is`

Tags: java, jackson

Sorry about the duplicate, the existing answers are not applicable/did not work for me. Example: [Jackson Not Overriding Getter with @JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843099/jackson-not-overriding-getter-with-jsonproperty)

Below is my object, it is still coming back as `zipValid` and `applianceTypeValid` however I am looking for `isZipValid` and `isApplianceTypeValid`.

During debugging, I noticed that this line `jsonResponse.put("statusResponse", new JSONObject(responseStatus));` is where it gets changed to `zipValid` and `applianceTypeValid`. `responseStatus` has the correct values as expected, but the moment `responseStatus` is loaded into`jsonResponse`, gone. Don't know is this helps.

```
package com.dish.wfm.services.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.List;

public class ValidationDTO {

   private boolean isZipValid;

   private boolean isApplianceTypeValid;

   private List<String> partnerEnabledProductTypes;

   @JsonProperty(value="isZipValid")
   public boolean isZipValid() {
       return isZipValid;
   }

   public void setZipValid(boolean zipValid) {
       isZipValid = zipValid;
   }

   @JsonProperty(value="isApplianceTypeValid")
   public boolean isApplianceTypeValid() {
       return isApplianceTypeValid;
   }

   public void setApplianceTypeValid(boolean applianceTypeValid) {
       isApplianceTypeValid = applianceTypeValid;
   }

   public List<String> getPartnerEnabledProductTypes() {
       return partnerEnabledProductTypes;
   }

   public void setPartnerEnabledProductTypes(List<String> partnerEnabledProductTypes) {
       this.partnerEnabledProductTypes = partnerEnabledProductTypes;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just added a main method creating a new ObjectMapper and writing your DTO as a string, and I see isZipValid in the output. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem and tell which version of Jackson you're using.

Comment: Show input JSON

Comment: From which package `JSONObject` comes from?

Comment: @JB Nizet, I'm not at the office right now however here is my version:      ```<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>```

Comment: @MichałZiober org.json.JSONObject is the package.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko `responseStatus = {ResponseStatus@8340} 
 statusCode = "0"
 statusMessage = "OK"
 flagName = null
 isFlagStatus = false
 status = true
 sealedFlagName = null
 isSealedFlagStatus = false
 sealedStatus = false
 isZipValid = true
 isApplianceTypeValid = true
jsonResponse = {JSONObject@8341} "{"queues":{"agentName":"","partnerEnabledProductTypes":[],"cancelFlag":"","productType":"","status":"COMPLETED"}}"` is the object before inserting into `JSONObject`

Comment: Why do you use `org.json.JSONObject`? You can just write: `jsonResponse.put("statusResponse", responseStatus);`

Comment: @MichałZiober Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `org.json.JSONObject` if you already use `Jackson`. Just write it as below:

```
jsonResponse.put("statusResponse", responseStatus);
```