# @JsonProperty name with spaces

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it allowed to have spaces in `@JsonProperty` name? i.e.

```
@JsonProperty("Jon Snow")
private String jonSnow = "Lord";

// getter & setter are omitted
```

I expect to get the following output:

```
{
   "Jon Snow" : "Lord"
}
```

But the actual result is:

```
{
   "jonSnow" : "Lord"
}
```

I use jackson-core v2.8.8, jackson-databind v2.8.8.1, and jackson-annotations v2.8.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `@JsonProperty` annotation from the wrong Jackson library.

I had `import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;` (Jackson v1) which I had to change to `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;` (Jackson v2), to be consistent with the library I was using.

I've found the answer in comments to this question: [@JsonProperty not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21125173/1429387)